# connection string of jdbc odbc with MS access

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to make jdbc ODBC connection with MS Access
but not able to pass the password which is consisted from special characters

I am using the following code:

```java
try
{
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "Jdbc:Odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver(*.mdb); DBQ=d:/abc/xyz.mdb};","","password here"
    );
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{

}
```

but this is not recognising the password here even the password is much complex (combination of special characters)

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: it doesnt read the password

Comment: What does this mean "doesn't read" the password? By the way, Does the password by any means have `"` (double quote) or `\\` (backslash) character in it?

Comment: Your connection string doesn't seem right, the syntax highlighting is off. You've got a part consisting of `""`, that's redundant: might as well leave it out. Fix the string first and see if it still gives problems. If so: show us the exact error.

Comment: You should use `jdbc:odbc:driver` instead (all lowercase)

Comment: where is your user name?And are you sure there is a "space" in your password?

Comment: i got the answer pass the user name and password as uname="username" and pwd="password"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following connection string for JDBC-ODBC is working correctly.

```java
try
{
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    String connectionQuery = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=path upto the database;uid=; pwd=password here;";  
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionQuery,"",""); 
    st=con.createStatement();
    stmt=con.createStatement();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    System.out.println("exception is"+ex);
}
```

Comment: JDBC ODBC Connectivity is going to removed from JDK8