# jdbc odbc connection using password with ms access

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to make connection in jdbc with MS Access. The connection is being established successfully but it's not taking the password in the connection string. I am using the following code.

```
try 
 {
  Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
  String connquery="jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver(*.mdb)};
  DBQ=d:/newfolder/db11.mdb";

  Connection c=DriverManager.getConnection(connquery,"","securityserver");
  Statement st=c.createStatement();
 }
 catch(Exception ex)

 {
 ex.printStackTrace();

 }
```

This connection is working properly without password but after applying the password it's throwing an exception.

Comment: general error unable to open temporarily jet DSN ..............

Comment: possible duplicate of [connection string of jdbc odbc with MS access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278634/connection-string-of-jdbc-odbc-with-ms-access)

Comment: You sure are having a lot of problems with this....

Comment: @duffymo whats wrong with this code

Comment: and how you are changing your password?

Comment: it worked i passed the username as uid="" pwd="password" then it worked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You've been at this for days.  Honestly, it's not that hard to connect to a relational database using Java.

I don't know what the deal is with Microsoft Access.  I've used it before on small problems with minor success, but I wouldn't recommend it now that there are so many other alternatives available.

MySQL or PostgreSQL are probably beyond you, but I'd say you'll have better luck with the Derby database that's built into the JDK.

The JDBC-ODBC driver is a problem; it's not available if you're on a 64 bit OS.  Access is for individual use; I wouldn't trust it for shared access.  You're having problems with passwords; others won't be so reluctant to accept a password.

Change your database if you can and see if that helps.

Comment: i got the answwer give like uid=username and pwd =password